# Обновление счётчика. Python. Random Choice

Tags: python, list, случайные-числа

Есть вот такой код для простой игрушки:

```
from time import sleep
from random import choice
from random import randrange

ee_names = [
    "Злая крыса", "Не очень-то злой филин", 
    "Чуть озверевший голубь", "Простуженная улитка" 
]

hp = randrange(3,10)
ename = choice(ee_names)

list_ = [
    (ename, hp),
    (ename, hp),
    (ename, hp),
]

name, hp = choice(list_)

for x in range(5):
    print( "[",name,"]\nHP: "+str(hp) )
    sleep(1)
```

Проблема в том, что каждый раз выводится одно и тоже имя с одними и теме же параметрами (*hp*). Как можно обновить счётчик? В *C++*, помню, было **srand(time(0))**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Результаты одинаковы потому, что вы их формируете не в цикле, а до него. Из задачи не ясно, зачем вам *list_*, поэтому можно поступить так:

```
from time import sleep
from random import choice, randrange


ee_names = [
    'Злая крыса', 
    'Не очень-то злой филин', 
    'Чуть озверевший голубь', 
    'Простуженная улитка'
]


for _ in range(5):
    name = choice(ee_names)
    hp = randrange(3, 10)

    print('[%s]\nHP: %s' % (name, hp))
    sleep(1)
```

В ходе исполнения наносится пять ударов, атакующий NPC и урон выбирается псевдослучайным образом.

Answer (score 2):

`randrange()` возвращает целое число. `hp = randrange(3,10)` присваивает этому возвращаемому значению имя `hp`. Повторение этого имени в программе не изменяет это целое число и не заставляет `hp` ссылаться на какое-либо другое число.

Аналогично, `choice(ee_names)` возвращает строку. `ename = choice(ee_names)` присваивает этой строке имя `ename`. Повторение этого имени в программе не изменяет эту строку и не заставляет `ename` ссылаться на какую-либо другую строку.

То есть *все* элементы в `list_` списке равны друг другу и поэтому `choice(list_)` *всегда* возвращает эквивалентные значения в этому случае.

`hp` не изменяется внутри цикла, поэтому все итерации показывают *одно и то же* значение.

Более того целые числа и строки неизменяемы в Питоне, единственный способ "изменить" `hp` это присвоить *новое* значение (обычно `=` знак используется, чтобы имя стало указывать на новый объект, но это не единственный способ, например `import` связывает различные объекты из других моделей с именами в текущем модуле).

Рекомендую на [картинки рядом с заголовком "В Python есть «имена»" из "Code Like a Pythonista: Idiomatic Python" by David Goodger](http://habrahabr.ru/post/89735/) посмотреть и на [презентацию Ned Batchelder c Pycon 2015, где этот вопрос более подробно изложен](http://pyvideo.org/video/3466/facts-and-myths-about-python-names-and-values) (код и картинки на слайдах), чтобы понять взаимоотношение между именами и их значениями в Питоне.

Даже если бы `hp` имя ссылалось бы на функцию, которая генерирует новое значение, то не хватает скобочек `()`, чтобы вызвать её. В некоторых языках употребление скобок может быть опционально, но в Питоне скобки обязательны:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
import random
from functools import partial

ee_names = [
    u'Злая крыса', 
    u'Не очень-то злой филин', 
    u'Чуть озверевший голубь', 
    u'Простуженная улитка'
]

generate_name = partial(random.choice, ee_names)
generate_hp = partial(random.randrange, 3, 10)
for _ in range(5):
    print(u"[{name}]\n\tHP: {hp}".format(name=generate_name(), hp=generate_hp()))
    time.sleep(1)
```

`partial()` просто запоминает данные ей аргументы и использует их при последующих вызовах.

Здесь лучше вставить реализацию функций прямо по месту, как показано в [ответе @idle sign](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419191/23044).

Answer (score 0):

В Python для этого используется функция `random.seed`:

```
import random
from datetime import datetime
random.seed(datetime.now())
```

Comment: Не срабатывает: всё также выдаёт одни и те же значения.

Comment: одни и те же при разных запусках скрипта или вы про те значения, которые в цикле выводятся ?